# change structure of old project to be able to navigate code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't navigate through the code for an old project involving many classes. in eclipse, for example, holding Ctrl when clicking on a class/method/interface doesn't open it.

How can I define the path of this class so that I can navigate through the code in Eclipse?

Comment: Did you mean `Ctrl + B`?

Comment: no for examplr  Holding Ctrl when clicking on a class/method/interface dont opens , eclipse dont know the path of class

Comment: can you open the file(s) outside of eclipse?

Comment: yes i can open any file outside on eclipse

Comment: i really don't know what you mean by control click. when i control click it's the same as a right-click with a mouse... it brings up a large menu for me to select from.

Comment: when you do ctrl +click on class, eclipse bring you to the class

Comment: for example User a ; if i do ctrl +clic on User ;eclipse open user definition class

Answer (score 2):

Make you sure you have imported it as `java project` and make sure that the `java facet` is set in the project properties.

If not just remove the project from eclipse **without deleting sources from disk**, remove eclipse files (.classpath, .project, and .settings) from project directory on disk and import it again as java project. If you have a `pom.xml` import as existing maven project.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a new project in eclipse and import only the sources.

Comment: java facet  in not set in in the project properties.i should configure it .?

Comment: @issamzebdi, yes you should add it (check the box and select the correct java version for your sources in the dropdown), if it still does not help, then do a fresh import as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There can be scenarios where `Ctrl` + `Click` do not work, and in order to solve that you may want to check the below options in the order mentioned as below:

1. You may just have to restart your Eclipse IDE once to check if this is solved
2. If Step-1 doesn't solve, you might want to add the `-clean` parameter to the command line argument to the `eclipse.exe` executable.
3. You need to check whether your Java project's build path is all correct without any errors/issues.
4. At times if this option is ('Project' -> 'Build Automatically') selected, you might have to do a 'Project' -> 'Clean...' to clean your projects
5. If Steps 1,2,3 and 4 do not solve your problem then you can take a backup of your project folder and then clean this `WORKSPACE_FOLDER/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core`
6. If the following didn't help then you can check for the following option to be available on your Eclipse IDE as well

   ```
   On Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking -> Open Declaration
   ```

   You need to check whether the `Default modifier key` is `Ctrl` and also ensure to select the checkbox for `Enable on demand hyperlink style navigation`

Hope this helps to resolve your issue!